# How do I return from a mobile application to a web page?

Tags: android, android-intent, mobile

We have a groovy web app for mobile devices. Now we want to "do some stuff" locally that can't be done in a browser, *and return the result to the web app*. On Android, [this page](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/android/intents) describes how to launch an activity from an intent url, but forgets to tell me how to return a result to the web page. Can this be done? The example given is a barcode scanner, so I presume the web page eventually gets to know the scanned code?

For bonus points, is there an equivalent mechanism for IOS? For windows phone? Would we better making a request for media capture? Or an ajax request for a local url?

Comment: you have to make runtime  url and have to call in browser

Comment: would the downvoter care to explain what they don't like?